# Can a 802.11ax device use 1024QAM of my 802.11ac router?

Tags: router, 802.11ac

I have an Asus Rapture GT-AC2900 802.11ac router and it is enabled for 1024QAM.
Can I use this feature if I connect a 802.11ax device?

Comment: I'm under the impression that 1024-QAM in 802.11ac was just a Broadcom thing. I suspect it is not generally interoperable with 802.11ax clients. So if your AX client uses a Broadcom chipset, then probably Yes, and if not, then probably No. But I don't know for sure. I'll leave this unanswered in case someone else knows for sure.